# Help with: Show that every $(X,d,x)$ in $\textbf{Met*}$ is isomorphic to a subspace of a product (in $\textbf{Met*}$) of copies of $\textbf{R}_+$

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

$\color{purple}{Background}$ $\color{purple}{Information}$

- *The category* $\textbf{Met*}.$ Let $\textbf{Met*}$ be the category whose objects are *metric spaces with base point* $(X,d,x)$ (meaning $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $x$ "the base point" is an arbitrary element of $X$) and whose morphisms $f(X,d,x)\to (Y,e,y)$ are contractions $f:(X,d)\to (Y,e)$ such that $fx=y.$ It is clear that $\textbf{Met*}$ is a category since if $fx=y$ and $gy=z$ then $gfx=gy=z.$
- Products in $\textbf{Met*}:$ *Every* family in $\textbf{Met*}$  has a product, although it need not be built on the cartesian product set!  Given $(X_i,d_i,x_i)$ let $X$ be the subset of all $I-$tuples $(a_i)$ with each $a_i\in X_i$ such that the $I-$tuple of numbers $d_i(a_i,x_i)$ has an upper bound, and define $d((a_i),(b_i))=\text{Sup }\{d_i(a_i,b_i)\mid i\in I\}.$  Then $x=(x_i)$ is in $X.$  Since there exist, by definition of $X,$ numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $d_i(a_i,x_i)\leq t$ for all $i$ and $d_i(b_i,x_i)\leq s$ for all $i$ then $$d_i(a_i,b_i)\leq d_i(a_i,x_i)+d_i(x,b_i)=d_i(a_i,x_i)+d_i(b_i,x_i)\leq t+s$$
  which proves that $d((a_i),(b_i))$ is a well -defined number.  Let $p_i:(X,d_,x)\to (X_i,d_i,x_i)$ be the usual coordinate projections.

$\color{green}{Exercise:}$  Consider $\textbf{R}_+$ to be $\textbf{Met*}$ with the usual metric and $0$ as base point.

Show that every $(X,d,x)$ in $\textbf{Met*}$ is isomorphic to a subspace of a product (in $\textbf{Met*}$) of copies of $\textbf{R}_+$

[Hint:  For any $y\in X, f_y:(X,d,x)\to \textbf{R}_+, z\mapsto d(y,z)-d(y,x)$ is a morphism in $\textbf{Met*}.$]

$\color{blue}{Question}$/$\color{blue}{difficulties:}$

From the hint, we have, $f_y(x)=d(y,x)-d(y,x)=0.$ Suppose $x_1\neq x_2\in X,$ then $e(f_y(x_1),f_y(x_2))=|f_y(x_1)-f_y(x_2)|=|(d(y,x_1)-d(y,x))-(d(y,x_2)-d(y,x))|=|d(y,x_1)-d(y,x_2)|\leq d(x_1,x_2)>0$

I am not sure what to do from here.  My $\textbf{main difficulties}$ are several:

not knowing how to translate:

"subspace of a product (in $\textbf{Met*}$) of copies of $\textbf{R}_+$" into math notation, not clear on what the product of $\textbf{Met*}$ look like in terms of coordinates from the description I cited from the text.  So if we let

$a=(a_i)_{i\in I}, b=(b_i)_{i\in I},$ then $d(a,b)=d((a_i), (b_i))=\text{Sup }\{d_i(a_i,b_i)\mid i\in I\}.$  I am not sure if this is correct.

I do know that I have to show the isomorphism is also an isometry. Lastly, I don't know how the hint is relevant to the question.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $\textbf{R}_+$ the set of positive real numbers? If so, the hint saying that it contains $d(y,z)-d(y,x)$ is dubious.

Comment: @AnneBauval I edited my post with a screenshot of the exercise.  Also, can I ask you to take a look at another following  [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718234/help-with-show-that-every-x-d-x-in-textbfmet-is-isomorphic-to-a-subsp) of mine. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. Since you retyped it,  I rolled back to not overload your post. I think $\textbf{R}_+$ denotes $(\Bbb R,m,0)$ where $m$ is the usual metric.

Comment: @AnneBauval I had to repost my comment since I asked you to look over the same post by mistake.  :)

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry again, this is the other post I want to ask if you can have a look at.  I keep posting the link to the wrong post:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718253/help-with-show-that-there-is-no-structure-d-x-in-textbfmetx-such-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us embed $(X,d,x)$ (isometrically) into the $\textbf{Met*}$-product $(Y,d',{\bf0})$ of the family, indexed by $X$, of copies of $\textbf{R}_+=(\Bbb R,m,0)$ (where $m$ is the usual metric). This is  [Kuratowski's embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_embedding).

$f:X\to Y$ is defined by

$$\forall y\in X\quad f(y)=f_y=(f_y(z))_{z\in X}$$
where $f_y$ was given by the hint:
$$f_y(z)=d(y,z)-d(x,z).$$

$f(y)\in Y$ since $(|f_y(z)-0|)_{z\in X}$ is bounded (by $d(x,y)$).

$f$ is an isometry since
$$\begin{align}d'(f(y_1),f(y_2))&=\sup_{z\in X}|f_{y_1}(z)-f_{y_2}(z)|\\&=\sup_{z\in X}|d(y_1,z)-d(y_2,z)|\\&=d(y_1,y_2)\end{align}$$ (because this upper bound is attained for instance when $z=y_1$).

This ends the proof.

Comment: wow, I am wondering why my topology course was never taught Kuratowski embedding.  I feel short changed.  I need to go back and ask for a bit of change back from my uni.  Also, thank you for showing me how this question is done.

Comment: @Seth It is good to accept answers when the question is resolved